# Sending Mass Emails in Acumatica does not show in Outlook Web APP on Mobile

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica Mass Email Option sends Email with Inserted Images to all contacts. The Email gets displayed on the MS Outlook 2013/2016 without any issues. However all images are shown as attached documents while displaying in Outlook Web APP on the Mobile.

The images are stored in MASS Email (######) where ##### is Mass Email ID. The html generated shows

What is to be done to have the image appearing on Mobile Browser ??

Answer (score 1):

Outlook web client has limited support for inline image. An image referenced in the body of a message will not show up if the source of the image isn't a web reference. Attached image are blocked in the body while image referenced by URL are let through.

Comment: The requirement is different ! There is an image inserted into the Customer-> Entry -> Mass Mail Option INSERT -> IMAGE ->Browse the file and Upload Ok ! The message is transmitted as required and it appears in MS Outlook ! .The problem is that when seen in Outlook Web APP, it is not appearing. Trying to send the same image from Web Refernce - Image is blocked message appears.

Comment: Your only options are to upload it to an allowed website reference URL for your target email client or get your email verified by the email client provider. If Outlook Web decides to block images coming from attachment /unknown URL or unverified senders, there's no way around that.

Comment: If the customer is unhappy with that, he'll have to ask the recipients to  configure their email client to accept the images: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/catastrophic_failure_joannav/2013/04/26/how-to-turn-off-blocked-feature-in-owa-outlook-web-app/

Comment: The Customer has a simple requirement ! To send newsletter of new products with images and feature list to prospective and customers who subscribe to the Newsletter ! The Acumatica database stores in its database all the Business Accounts (Customers and Prospects) The Mass mail is expected to send the newsletter, why can't it be sent to a mobile device. ?? Attachment is no solution ! The prospect or customer has to have a good glance if he just watches his mobile !

Comment: Allowing newsletters to slip by email client spam filters is not a simple requirement. It's arguably an impossible one if you can't get access to the customer device and configure his email client to remove images  blocking. Your best option is to contact the email client company (Microsoft/Google/Apple/Yahoo) and ask them to get the company domain sending the newsletter to get verified and whitelisted. From their point of view, your newsletter sent from an unverified sender is spam and images are blocked to prevent email address confirmation by image loading.